# SSRS is assuming the wrong column datatype

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that's being built from a stored procedure given 2 variables. The error I'm receiving is

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot read the next data row for the dataset Sheet2.     (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.5' to data type int.
```

This doesn't make any sense. The variable in question is being stored as a varchar. I don't do any typecasting in the stored procedure. Executing the stored proc in sql server studio works fine. In the query designer I replaced the stored procedure call with just the code for the stored procedure and it works fine as well. Switching it back to call the stored procedure throws the same error.

Why is SSRS trying to convert a varchar to an int? It should be a double if anything or just leave it alone and not try typecasting it at all.

Comment: That is an odd one. Is this error happening when you are using the designer in Visual Studio? I've seen some odd behavior before, though usually with trying to determine field names, that never present themselves when run on the actual service. The only other thing that I could think of is if you are applying any kind of values in the "Format" property of a text box.

Comment: @MartinSoles In Visual Studio and on the SSRS reporting server. That's how it was brought to my attention.

Comment: Try looking at the XML behind the report. Field types are included in the dataset but not surfaced in the designer. Perhaps it got flagged as an integer somehow (like when the report was initially developed, it was an integer but is now a varchar after the stored procedure was updated).

Comment: @MartinSoles The rd:TypeName was System.Int32. Changing it to System.String did nothing. It has something to do with the version I'm using. Our prod server is using 2008 and our dev one is using 2010 and I'm using 2013 VS. I pulled the working version off of prod and it gives the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure how much I can help after that one hint. I currently don't have access to the specific versions of SSRS that you are working with (we have 2005 and 2012 running on two different machines right now).

Comment: @MartinSoles Found my answer. The stored procedures differed between prod and dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the technical details when I ran it in the query designer and found the error was originating from the stored procedure and not involving SSRS at all. When I tested the stored proc the first time I tested the production version and not the development version. The development stored proc I use to test reports in VS and the database that houses this stored proc is the development database. The dev server obviously also uses the dev database version as well.

For some reason this line of code breaks it

```
CASE WHEN TN_UNPLATED_BLANK.CN_ZZ_ANGLE_TOL_MINUTES = '-32767' THEN -999999
     ELSE TN_UNPLATED_BLANK.CN_ZZ_ANGLE_TOL_MINUTES END AS CN_ZZ_ANGLE_TOL_MINUTES,
```

Changing it to this fixes it

```
CASE WHEN TN_UNPLATED_BLANK.CN_ZZ_ANGLE_TOL_MINUTES = '-32767' THEN NULL
     ELSE TN_UNPLATED_BLANK.CN_ZZ_ANGLE_TOL_MINUTES END AS CN_ZZ_ANGLE_TOL_MINUTES,
```

It's as if the return type of the else portion forced the string '`-32767'` to convert to an int and then forcing the `.5` to typecast to an int causing the error to be thrown.

Comment: That was definitely a head scratcher. I'm glad that you figured it out.